# unable to insert records in database

Tags: php, mysql

starting query to display result:

```
$at = array();
    $num=array();
    $i=0;
    while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
      echo  $rw['c_number'] 
      $number=$rw['c_number'];
        $num[$i]=$number;
          $i++;
       echo $rw['total'];
       $at[] = $rw['total'];
     }
```

//  the result of this query is like:

```
 Mobile numbers bills
    03455919448 34
    03215350700 56
    03474738923 678
    03573987932 344
    03187438979 1324
```

// now want to insert it in database

```
    $d= 'november';
     foreach($num as $num1){
    $sql = "insert into billing details(bill,month/year,c_number) values  ('$at','$d','$num')";
     mysql_error();
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

// the insertion query at end is not working and gives me error:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
```

Comment: So you're checking for the error **before** executing your query? Is this code supposed to be run on a quantum computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace num with num1 like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `billing details`(bill,`month/year`,c_number) VALES  ('$at','$d','$num1')";
```

And dont use mysql_* functions due to they are depricated,instead you use mysqli_* functions or PDO statements

**AND put your table name in '`' it seems like two different names and for the column name month/year also**

Comment: What's about `month/year`?

Comment: I think he had a column like that...??

Comment: do you think mysql will recognize it as a single column name not as a division operation?

Comment: Yep, it would be helpful to add backticks for `month/year`

Comment: He need to put the table name also I think

Comment: basically i want to insert all mobile numbers along wd their bills in database... $num is a temporary variable to hold an array... please check the table above and guide me how to store that entire table in database table - billing details - with columns - bill,month/year,c_number

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what exactly want to insert $num  or $num1 ? and check your table name ,column names

```
$d= 'november';
int i=0;  // you are saying that $at has all bills
 foreach($num as $num1){
$sql = "insert into billing details(bill,month/year,c_number) values  ('$at[i]','$d','$num1[mobile_number]')";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if (mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed');
 i++;
}
```

Comment: And how to guess the reason the query failed after that?

Comment: there is nothing to guess .just should knoq how execute mysql in php and how to define table name and column names ?

Comment: well, without a particular error you cannot be sure about the reason of query's fail. And `Error, insert query failed` isn't helpful.

Comment: basically i want to insert all mobile numbers along wd their bills in database... $num is a temporary variable to hold an array...  please check the table above and guide me how to store that entire table in database table - billing details -  with columns - bill,month/year,c_number

Comment: then what is $at ? first tell $num is a array what? imean $num1 contains what ??@user2467657

Comment: $at holds all bills in an array and same goes for $num...i mean if u echo $at it gives u all bills and same for $num.. gives u all numbers